# If and then statement for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to have the index view put "true" if the reading  column equals 1.

I've tried placing this code in different places wit no results:

```
if student.listening == 1 
  puts "Yes"
else
  puts "No"
```

Here's the github link: https://github.com/keithgordon/classroom

Comment: `puts` writes to stdout by default, which is not the same as rendering.

Comment: Did it work for you? :)

Comment: what is the correct way instead of put?

Comment: You just write whatever you want to write :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display a string inside a view, just do:

```
 <% if student.listening == 1 %>
  Yes
 <% else %>
  No
 <% end %>
```

I guess something like this should work too:

```
<%= (student.listening == 1) ? 'Yes' : 'No' %>
```

[edit]
In the comments it turned out that the '1' is a string. So the correct statement is:

```
 <% if student.listening == "1" %>
  Yes
 <% else %>
  No
 <% end %>
```

as "1" == 1 are not equal

Comment: The later would "work" if the requirements were different, or a ternary expression was added.

Comment: Thanks, I hope that I understood you correctly.

Comment: @jmeier After using the first solution. I receive this error  Users/Keith/code/classroom/app/views/students/index.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...nd=(if student.listening == 1 );@output_buffer.safe_append=' I updated github with my current code

Comment: remove the leading "="! sorry for that

Comment: @jmeier All of my entries say no instead of yes. Any advice?

Comment: Check if listening is really 1... add this to check it: <%= student.listening %>

Comment: yes a few of the listening are 1

Comment: and still no? Try student.listening == "1"

Comment: <%= student.listening == "1" %> works but here's the end result http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2013-10-20_at_3.26.22_PM-2e41zNzI.png

Comment: Whats the problem? Your question seems to be answered. I updated my answer - please accept it again :) - to your problem: I guess you forgot to put the code into both cases...